# Is it possible to define the coordinates of centers with make_blobs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, centering

I would like to create 1 blob whose center would be (x,y) = (1,5) with make_blobs from sklearn.datasets. I currently use the following script to generate but the created blob is set with x and y centers randomly between 1 and 5.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=30, center_box=(1,5), cluster_std=0.05,centers=1)
```

How please could I force the center of the blob to be (1,5) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may [specify](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) any number of centers for you blobs in `centers` param:

> `centers`: int or array of shape [n_centers, n_features], optional
>   (default=None) The number of centers to generate, **or the fixed center locations**. If n_samples is an int and centers is None, 3 centers are generated. If n_samples is array-like, centers must be either None or an array of length equal to the length of n_samples

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=300, n_features=2, cluster_std=.1
                  ,centers= [(1,5), (2,10)])
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c=y);
```

[image]